# Sqlite creating a db and inserting data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sqlite

I am new in programming and in Ruby on Rails. So, i just created a new rails project and i want to insert data into the database. I am using sqlite3 and i am working in Windows. I created a table Products with attributes: name, description and price. I want to specify data for each attribute, for example name: Shoes and so on. How can i insert data into the database using command line? I googled my problem, but i have not found clear answer. Could any one help me or give me a link with helpful information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
rails c
product = Product.new
product.name = 'Shoes'
product.description = 'description'
product.price = 99.9
product.save
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I've been looking for!